# React deploy fails in CSS file

Tags: css, reactjs, build, github-pages

i'm getting this error whenever i try to build my react app for github-pages. It fails at  first Css file, after some investigation i got idea that it has some problem with webpack.config, but can someone be more specific and help me to solve this problem? Thanks.

[image: Error]

here is the CSS file https://gist.github.com/Saba1121/ebd1da3ebc9ec2c3dab8a28a95388f66

Comment: share Css file with github gist . your css have sentex issue

Comment: @AurangzaibRana  here : https://gist.github.com/Saba1121/ebd1da3ebc9ec2c3dab8a28a95388f66

Answer (score 0):

```
:root {
  /*--headerHeight : 40px;*/
}
```

Just comment it out and it will resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it. Problem was that i used "calc()" function inside another "calc()" function, after commenting it out build completed succesfully.